# A complement to a set of spheres in a sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, spheres

Take $S^n$ and consider a set $Z$ of $k_1$ circles, $k_2$ 2-dimensional spheres, .., $k_{n-2}$ $n-2$-dimenional spheres in $S^n$ (there spheres do not intersect inside $S^n$). I want to understand what is $S^n \setminus Z$. To do this, I calculated homology of this space via Mayer-Vietoris and I think that the complement is homotopy equivalent to $(S^{n-1})^{k_1+k_2+..+k_{n-2}-1} \vee (S^{n-2})^{k_1} \vee .. \vee (S^{1})^{k_{n-2}}$. Is it true? Where can I find a reference? The problem is that we cannot deduce this isomorphism from knowing homology, is there any way to see this explicitly?

Comment: In the first nontrivial case, $n = 3$, your question specialises to the homology of knot complements.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Probably, I also want them to be non-linked whatever that means (do homology depend on it?)

Comment: Even if you just take a single circle in $S^3$, its complement can have nontrivial fundamental group when the circle is embedded in a knotted manner. So for your conjecture to hold, you'll need to assume that your embedded spheres (or I guess really just the $(n-2)$-dimensional ones) are embedded in a non-knotted way --- whatever that means... :)

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Oh, right. Then I want them all to be unknotted. So, I want to consider the simplest case ever. Is my suggestion correct in this case?

Comment: I don't know. I'm aware that $S^n\setminus S^k$ should be homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-k-1}$ which is consistent with your conjecture. I guess a second toy case I'd try is to consider the complement of two unlinked circles in $S^3$.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Right, that is exactly how I did it. For two circles we get $S^3$ = union of A and B which are complements to $S^1$. In particular, they are homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ and then use  $0 \to H_3 (S^3) \to H_2 (X) \to 0  => H_2 (X) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_2 (S^3) \to H_1 (X) \to \mathbb{Z}^2 \to 0 => H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}^2$, so I think $X$ is a wedge of $S^2$ and two circles..